# Eclipse project (Facets) icons

Tags: eclipse, maven, facet

[image: Eclipse Icons Project]

As you can see in the image above, instead of the **J** in my workspace appear that brown thing, i realize is something related to **Project Facets** and its just IDE related as some research says, someone even says to delete all `<natures>` tags  from **.project** file in project but it doenst work. So i would like to know how to restore it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deleting `<natures>` in the .project will wreck the project - very bad advice. Do not touch the .project file unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 of course i wouldnt delete all tags from projoects. Anyway i found my "own" solution and i will post as answer, maybe can be useful for someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i found the solution for restoring the original behaviour, i just deleted `<natures>` tags in the **.project** files, keeping the following:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
</natures>
```